# File "Customer Access" Permissions

Tags: community, sharing, lightning-community, files

In Winter'20 there was added feature to allow "Customer Access" for files. Some of the users need to have access to it. Maybe someone knows or played with that?
For the target user, this is just ReadOnly currenty.
l
In [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=networks_files_on_records_visible_to_customers.htm) it doesn't say about required permissions and I tried adding some of the Administration permissions for Files and Communities, but it didn't work.

Any ideas?
[image: f]